# Using ZonedDateTime with Grails 3 lastUpdated and dateCreated fields

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Does Grails 3 provide support for the use of any class other than Date, such as ZonedDateTime, for the dateCreated and lastUpdated fields? For example,

```
...
ZonedDateTime dateCreated
ZonedDateTime lastUpdated
...
```

I know that MySQL supports ZonedDateTime, so I'm mostly curious if GORM has support for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. Since Grails 3 still supports down to java 7 you need to add a few dependencies in your build.gradle to add support for it:

```
// Hibernate java 8 java.time support 
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:$hibernateVersion" 
// Grails java 8 java.time support
compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-java8:1.2.3"
```

There's a lot of good tips when using java.time with Grails here: https://giri-tech.blogspot.com/2018/01/add-time-zone-sense.html

Answer (score 0):

Natively, no.  However, it would be quite trivial for you to use those yourself if you prefer.  You would want to first turn off autotimestamping on your domain object:

```
static mapping = {
    autoTimestamp false
}
```

Then use events (beforeUpdate, beforeInsert) to populate like:

```
def beforeUpdate() {
    lastUpdated = // whatever you want it to be
}
```